# Opposite of SWITCH function? (i.e. enums in Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In programming, I could use a switch/case statement to do something like this:

```
func animalNameFromType(animalType: Int) {
  switch animalType {
    case 1: return "dog"
    case 2: return "cat"
    case 3: return "bird"
  }
}

animalNameFromType(2) == "cat"
```

The equivalent in Google Sheets is the SWITCH function:

```
=SWITCH(<value>, 1, "dog", 2, "cat", 3, "bird")
```

However, in programming, I could also do the opposite and return the index of an item in a list:

```
["dog", "cat", "bird"].indexOf("cat") == 2
```

How do I do something similar in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are essentially using an ENUM in Google Sheets and the index is increasing by exactly one in each case, your best bet is to use [arrays](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en).

If you had a more complicated mapping between integers to strings, you should use the SWITCH function.

Here are examples in both directions (Int to String, and String to Int)...

**Option 1:** via arrays (preferred)

```
=Index({"dog", "cat", "bird"}, 1, <index>) // e.g. if <index> is 2, it'll return "cat"
=MATCH(<value>, {"dog", "cat", "bird"}, 0) // e.g. if <value> is "cat", it'll return 2
```

**Option 2:** via `SWITCH` function

```
=SWITCH(<index>, 1, "dog", 2, "cat", 3, "bird") // e.g. if <index> is 2, it'll return "cat"
=SWITCH(<value>, "dog", 1, "cat", 2, "bird", 3) // e.g. if <value> is "cat" it'll return 2
```

Comment: related:[Compare single cell to multiple values](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106638/88163)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function to use `Array.prototype.indexOf` as it's shown in the question. Next is a simple implementation:

```
/**
 *
 * @param {Array} values
 * @param {String|Integer} searchElement
 * @customfunction
 */
function indexOf(values,searchElement){
  return values.indexOf(searchElement);
}
```

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions